# Convergence of power series with factorial ratio coefficients

Tags: calculus, functions, power-series, absolute-convergence

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:2^{2n}\cdot \frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}x^n$$

Using ratio test we can see that radius of convergence is $R = 1$. Though I'm not sure how to find the exact function in a closed form, like $\frac{1}{1-x}$ with $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:x^n$. My idea is to find some relation with other functions, like $f(x) = (1-x^2)f'(x)$ and then deduce the answer, but I'm kind of stuck. Could you give hints for this problem?

Comment: See https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2016/07/26/generating-function-for-the-reciprocals-of-the-central-binomial-coefficients/ (in you case, $x$ is replacd by $4x$)

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate the function that your series represents as follows:

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} \frac{(2^n n!)^2}{(2n)!}x^n $$ and define the function $$\begin{align}g(t) = \frac{f(t^2)-1}{t}, \tag 1 \end{align}$$ with $ g(0)=0 $.   The power series for $g$ is easily deduced, $$ g(t)=\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{(2^nn!)^2}{(2n)!} t^{2n-1}. $$  As above, this series converges for $|t| \leqslant 1 $ and in this interval, $$\begin{align}tg'(t) &= \sum_{n\geqslant 1} (2n-1)\frac{(2^nn!)^2}{(2n)!}t^{2n-1} \\ &=2t +\sum_{n\geqslant2}(2n) \frac{(2^{n-1}(n-1)!)^2}{(2n-2)!}t^{2n-1}\\ &=\frac{d}{dt}\left(t^2+t^3\sum_{n\geqslant 2}\frac{(2^{n-1}(n-1)!)^2}{(2n-2)!}t^{2n-3} \right) \\ &= \frac{d}{dt}\left( t^2+t^3 \sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{(2^nn!)^2}{(2n)!}t^{2n-1} \right) \\ &=\frac{d}{dt} \left( t^2+t^3 g(t) \right) \end{align}.$$

This yields a first order differential equation for $g(t)$, which can be arranged as,
$$(1-t^2)g'(t)-3t g(t) = 2.$$
If we now apply an integrating factor of $(1-t^2)^{1/2}$, we obtain,
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left( (1-t^2)^{3/2}g(t) \right) = 2(1-t^2)^{1/2} = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \sin^{-1} (t) + t(1-t^2)^{1/2} \right). $$
This gives, using $g(0) = 0$,
$$ g(t) = \frac{\sin^{-1}(t)+t(1-t^2)^{1/2}}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}} $$
Inverting the definition of $g(t) $ gives, for $x \geq 0$,
$$
f(x) = 1+\sqrt{x} \cdot \frac{  \sin^{-1}( \sqrt x )+ \sqrt{x(1-x)}}{(1-x)^{3/2}}.
$$
Last, a similar argument is needed to derive the closed form for $f(x)$ when $x \leq 0$, by adapting equation $(1)$.  I believe the result is
$$
f(x) = 1-\sqrt{ |x| }\cdot \frac{\log(\sqrt{|x|} + \sqrt{1+|x|})+\sqrt{|x|(1+|x|)}}{(1+|x|)^{3/2}}.
$$
Combined, we find,
$$
f(x) = 1 + \frac{ x \sqrt{1-x} + \left\{ {\sqrt{x} \sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}, \quad\quad\quad\quad x  \geqslant 0 \atop \sqrt{-x} \log(\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{-x}), \quad x \leqslant 0} \right . }{(1-x)^{3/2}} $$
This is fairly complicated and I hope contains no mistakes.  Please let me know if I am wrong!

---

Additional comment (1):  I have checked numerically the closed form solution against the original power series over $-\frac{1}{2} \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ with agreement to 5 decimal places, so now reasonably confident the formula is OK.

---

Additional comment (2):  with acknowledgement to the comment below, when $x\leqslant 0$ the first expression continues to apply if the root of $\sqrt{x}$ is allowed complex values.  In this case, writing $\sqrt{x} = i\theta$, we obtain,
$$ (i\theta) \sin^{-1} i\theta = \theta \log (\sqrt{1+\theta^2} -\sqrt{\theta}) $$

Comment: You can avoid two cases in your formula.  When $x \le 0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is complex, so use the complex arcsine.  In fact, this works for complex $x$ with $|x| < 1/2$.

Comment: @Gedgar Thanks.  I was aware of that but elected to avoid complex arguments in the answer.  Also, for the avoidance of doubt the radius of convergence and validity of the formula is $|x| < 1$.  My test was limited to the smaller range because convergence of the power series slows down as $x$ approaches $1$.

Comment: The formula will hold up to the nearest singularity of the RHS.  Another (harder) way to establish that the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: GEdgar, thanks again.  I have added the complex arcsin equation in a second comment.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test gives:$$\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left|\frac{2^{2\left(\text{n}+1\right)}\cdot\frac{\left(\text{n}+1\right)!}{\left(2\left(\text{n}+1\right)\right)!}\cdot x^{\left(\text{n}+1\right)}}{2^{2\text{n}}\cdot\frac{\text{n}!}{\left(2\text{n}\right)!}\cdot x^\text{n}}\right|=\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\left|\frac{2x}{1+2\text{n}}\right|=0\tag1$$

> And the [closed-form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28%28%282%5E%282*%28n%29%29%29*%28%28%28n%29%21%29%2F%28%282*%28n%29%29%21%29%29*%28x%5E%28n%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D) of your sum is dependent on the error-function.

Comment: That should be $ |2(n+1) x / (2n+1)|$, No?.  Each term's numerator has $(n!)^2$. The limit is then $x$ and radius of convergence 1 as OP had it.